# Use <ReferenceInput /> data source for multiple inputs

Tags: react-admin

So I have a case where we need to select a total of 8 fonts (a primary and a secondary font in four weights each), and since these are named fields, they need to be individual input fields, and each field can potentially be assigned equal values if less typographic variation is wanted.

All these 8 fields use the exact same data source, let’s say they’re available at `/fonts` in our API.

The way we solved this temporarily, is to have 8 `<SelectInput>`s wrapped in individual `<ReferenceInput>`s like so;

```
<ReferenceInput source="fonts.<identifier>" reference="fonts">
    <SelectInput optionText="id"/>
</ReferenceInput>
```

This doesn’t perform all that well, and we are now wondering if it’s somehow possible to wrap multiple `<SelectInput>`s in some kind of ReferenceProvider, and have them all share the same data source?